# Pascal's Triangle output

Tags: python, algorithm

I wrote a code to generate Pascal's triangle.

```
def triangles():
    N = [1]
    while True:
        yield N
        N.append(0)
        N = [N[i-1] + N[i] for i in range(len(N))]
    #print the triangle 
    n = 0
    results = []
    for t in triangles():
        results.append(t)
        n = n + 1
        if n == 10:
            break
        print(t)
    print(results)
```

the print(t) gives the correct output

```
[1]
[1, 1]
[1, 2, 1]
[1, 3, 3, 1]
[1, 4, 6, 4, 1]
[1, 5, 10, 10, 5, 1]
[1, 6, 15, 20, 15, 6, 1]
[1, 7, 21, 35, 35, 21, 7, 1]
[1, 8, 28, 56, 70, 56, 28, 8, 1]
```

However the results list has an additional "0" at the end of each list .

```
[[1, 0], 
 [1, 1, 0], 
 [1, 2, 1, 0], 
 [1, 3, 3, 1, 0], 
 [1, 4, 6, 4, 1, 0], 
 [1, 5, 10, 10, 5, 1, 0], 
 [1, 6, 15, 20, 15, 6, 1, 0], 
 [1, 7, 21, 35, 35, 21, 7, 1, 0], 
 [1, 8, 28, 56, 70, 56, 28, 8, 1, 0], 
 [1, 9, 36, 84, 126, 126, 84, 36, 9, 1]]
```

I read some blogs and tried to add a "New_N" variable in the middle and it gives me correct result.

```
def triangles():
    N = [1]
    while True:
        yield N
        New_N = []
        for i in N:
            New_N.append(i)
        New_N.append(0)
        N = [New_N[i-1] + New_N[i] for i in range(len(New_N))]

    n = 0
    results = []
    for t in triangles():
        results.append(t)
        n = n + 1
        if n == 10:
            break
        print(t)
    print(results)
```

output:

```
[[1], 
 [1, 1], 
 [1, 2, 1], 
 [1, 3, 3, 1], 
 [1, 4, 6, 4, 1], 
 [1, 5, 10, 10, 5, 1], 
 [1, 6, 15, 20, 15, 6, 1], 
 [1, 7, 21, 35, 35, 21, 7, 1], 
 [1, 8, 28, 56, 70, 56, 28, 8, 1],
 [1, 9, 36, 84, 126, 126, 84, 36, 9, 1]]
```

It feels like results.append(t) breaks the order of the function, but I'm not too sure and I would like to know the rationale behind this. Could someone tell me why do I need a "New_N" variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lists are mutable. In the first code, `N.append(0)` tacks a `0` onto the end of the previous row, thus changing the row. `results` contains the lists themselves and not copies of the lists. Since you are changing the lists themselves, those changes are visible in `results`.

The second code creates a new list which is a copy of the previous row. Tacking on a `0` to the end of the new list doesn't effect the old list because, well, it is a brand new list.

Note that it would be more idiomatic to create the new list by `New_N = N.copy()` rather than by using an explicit loop.